# BIND Name Servers aren't returning my site

Tags: linux, bind, centos6, nameserver, website

I don't know much about BIND but I'm learning and my friend helped me setup my own name servers. He did this before and it worked for him so I think he forget a step and that explains why this isn't working. Anyways, we used webmin to setup bind and i'm pretty sure that's okay but I can post info just ask.

- So my domain is: dustinschreiber.com
- At my registrant, naemservers are set to: ns1.dustinschreiber.com and ns2.dustinschreiber (Each pointing to an IP address on my server, I have two IPs)
- whois shows my name servers are set right
- http://postimage.org/image/o6fz623cx/ (All records according to BIND, The blacked out ones are for a friend and irrelevant anyways)
- I haven't made any changes to the systems files I've done all work through webmin so I'm not sure if I was supposed to change another file.
- Doing `nslookup ns1.dustinschreiber.com` on the server returns no results but even after a few days and doing /flushdns on my computer it still returns the proper IPs for both NSs as well as typing them into my web browser. But I had my friend try and it timed out for him so maybe that's my problem but just adding as much info as I can

I can't think of anything else to post so just ask if you need more info. I have fiddled around with BIND through webmin but don't know what else to try and all tutorials I find on setting up BIND are by using the files (they also didn't work for me) but I am not afraid to use SSH (I am well experienced in it) to modify files.

Thank you for reading this! Can anyone offer any suggestions? It's been like two weeks so I know it's been updated through the DNS servers.

Its a CentOS 6 machine btw.

UPDATE

```
[root@dustinschreiber ~]# dig @199.168.139.127 dustinschreiber.com A

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.2 <<>> @199.168.139.127 dustinschreiber.com A
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23919
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dustinschreiber.com.           IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dustinschreiber.com.    38400   IN      A       199.168.139.127

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dustinschreiber.com.    1800    IN      NS      ns2.dustinschreiber.com.
dustinschreiber.com.    1800    IN      NS      ns1.dustinschreiber.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.dustinschreiber.com. 38400  IN      A       199.168.139.127
ns2.dustinschreiber.com. 38400  IN      A       199.168.139.148

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 199.168.139.127#53(199.168.139.127)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 12 21:40:03 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 121
```

UPDATE

I think I fixed it! Allow-query in named.conf was set to localhost (looking in the /var/logs/messages file showed hundreds of query attempts but it said they were denied) A bit more googling and research and I commented out the allow-query line and restarted BIND. (Default is allow-query { any;}; apparently) and it worked! I'm not sure how secure it really is like that but I think it's working alright. :D Well it works and I'm happy. :D You guys lead me in the right direction so now I know what I have to change to make nameservers for a startup company my friend is doing. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I get no reply from your nameservers.  Did you maybe forget to adjust the firewall rules to allow DNS traffic?

Comment: As far as I know the firewall is off.

Comment: Is your bind service running on the server? Can you see if port 53 is listening by running netstat -nltp

Comment: @Chida yes BIND is running. and listening on both my IP addresses on port 53

Comment: @Dustin: It definitively looks like a access-right error. Do you have any `allow-query` or `match-clients` in your configuration files?

Comment: @petrus yes I did have an allow query line, I just edited my question with my solution :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dns servers are refusing to answer :

```
$ dig @199.168.139.148 dustinschreiber.com A
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: **REFUSED**, id: 45216
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dustinschreiber.com.           IN      A

$ dig @199.168.139.127 dustinschreiber.com A
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: **REFUSED**, id: 25080
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dustinschreiber.com.           IN      A
```

So they are listening and working, but there might be an access-list in Bind that prevents clients to get the answer.

Comment: An access-list? Not that I can find at least. Looking in the conf file reveals nothing and Webmin I find "Access Control List" is empty.

Comment: Also, if I run the dig command you did on the BIND server itself (mind you I never edited the resolv file or the hosts file) I am presented with the updated info I posted in the question which leads me to think... well I have no idea actually :P

Comment: You got me going in the right direction (plus your the only one that left an actual "answer" I guess you would say) so I'm going to mark you as solution. Everyone else: read the bottom update on my original question for the full explanation and solution. Thank you once again!